# Qual é o melhor método em Rails para criar uma categoria autorreferenciada?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, gem

Gostaria de uma dica para criar uma categoria autorreferenciada onde sería possível adicionar categorias filha dela própria e assim suscetivamente com a finalidade de construir uma árvore utilizando o mesmo objeto.

Existe alguma gem ou uma forma fácil e bem otimizada de fazer isso?

Comment: Olá. Se me permite uma dica, a sua questão (e, principalmente, o título dela) parece um pouco subjetiva e propensa a receber opiniões como resposta. Esse tipo de questão não é desejada aqui (dê uma olhada nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). Talvez seja interessante editá-la (se possível, incluindo tentativas que você já realizou de criar a tal categoria) para tornar a pergunta mais específica. :)

Comment: Não sabia que era obrigado a ter código na página e nem que ninguém pode pedir sugestão mas valeu!!! Gostei da resposta do @CassioCabral

Comment: Não é uma questão de obrigar ou impedir. Eu realmente acho que sua pergunta *é interessante* para a comunidade, mas apenas sugeri pra você tentar torná-la um pouco melhor. O aspecto de objetividade é importante nesta comunidade assim como em todo o grupo StackExchange. Quando tiver um tempo leia essa (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) e essa (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao/160) thread. De todas as formas, eu não quis tolher a sua participação, ok? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ver essa gem [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

Como você deseja um modelo que se autorreferencia, mais especificamente para categoria e já que é para construir uma árvore. A gem ancestry já foi feita para esse tipo de caso.

Comment: Óptimo! +1 (vou remover o meu primeiro comentário)