# Como modelar categorias de produtos?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, modelagem

Estou prestes a iniciar o desenvolvimento de um e-commerce, mas estou travado na questão da modelagem, principalmente no que tange a categorias e subcategorias de produtos. Por exemplo. Uma categoria pode ter várias sub-categoias. Cada sub-categoria, pode também ter sub-sub-categorias (máximo de 3 níveis). Mais ou menos assim:

```
-Categoria
--Sub Categoria
---Sub-sub categoria
```

Como ficaria então isso no banco de dados? Seria um auto-relacionamento? Se sim, ou se não, alguém pode dar um exemplo?

Outra dúvida. Exemplo:

```
Vestiário
-- Camisetas
  -- Masculino
   ---- Camiseta M. pollo tam. G (produto)
```

Se essa camiseta pertence a masculino, então automaticamente percence a camisetas e vestuário. Usarei Rails, como eu implementaria esse tipo de comportamento lá?

Comment: Não conheço Rails, mas acho que o conceito de *scaffolding* dele pode ser útil.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: [link](http://rberaldo.com.br/categorias-e-subcategorias-exemplo-de-modelagem/)

Comment: Eu faria uma tabela de categorias com auto-relacionamento permitindo n subcategorias, o relacionamento com produtos seria algo do tipo produto--<produto_categoria>-----categoria , tentando resumir ..... (1) categoria refrigerante, sub colas , sub sem açucar /// (2) categoria dieteticos , sub refrigerantes , o produto motta-cola ligado as categorias (1) e (2)

Comment: Sobre a parte de modelagem do banco de dados, veja [Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/74). Sobre fazer isso no Rails não achei muita coisa aqui no site, mas talvez [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4313/qual-%C3%A9-o-melhor-m%C3%A9todo-em-rails-para-criar-uma-categoria-autorreferenciada) seja um começo.

Comment: @Motta Seu comentário é quase uma resposta, faltando só detalhar um pouco.

Comment: @Andrey , vou tentar detalhar como resposta, mas o tipo da pergunta que não tem uma só resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Basta você usar uma referência recursiva na criação do model Categoria e criar um contador de níveis para limitar a 3.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "category_id"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "category_id"

  # Valida para ser no máximo do terceiro nível (começa em zero)
  validates :level, :numericality => { :less_than_or_equal_to => 2 }

  # verifical dinâmicamente o nível da categoria
  def level
    parent.nil? ? 0 : parent.level + 1
  end
end
```

e no model de Produto, referenciar o model de Categoria

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Em relação ao banco de dados, a estrutura das tabelas ficou o seguinte:

Tabela: Categories

```
id (pk)
name
category_id (fk)
```

Tabela: Products

```
id (pk)
name 
category_id (fk)
```